# Writing edit to file removes contents instead of editing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, fwrite

**Problem**: Removes the content from the target file instead of editing and saving the file (original content+edited content)

**Want**: Hoping for the fix to be as close to **FuncB** as possible since this is an experiment for me

```py
#IMPORTS
import json
import os

#EXTERNAL VARIABLES/FUNCTIONS
cdl = str(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))+os.sep)
GetFileCont = lambda filename, extension="txt", dir=cdl: list(open(str(dir)+str(filename)+"."+str(extension)))

#FUNCTION TO FIX
def FuncB(filename:str, extension:str, line:int, new_data, dir=cdl):  # <--- After
    open(
        str(dir)+str(filename)+"."+extension, "w"
        ).writelines(
            [new_data+"\n" if (i+1)==line else v for i, v in enumerate(GetFileCont(str(filename), extension))]
            )
```

**Tried**: i have tried the long way (yes it works well) i just want to try and see if i can do it this way

```py
#OTHER WAY TO COMPLETE THE BROKEN FUNCTION
def FuncA(filename, extension, line, new_data, dir=cdl):  # <--- Before
    data = GetFileCont(str(filename), extension)
    data[line-1] = new_data+"\n"
    with open(str(dir)+str(filename)+"."+extension, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it as a one-liner like that. The argument to `writelines()` isn't evaluated until after `open()` returns, and when you call `open()` with `w` mode it truncates the file. So you're trying to read the file after it has been emptied.

You could use `r+` mode instead. This opens the file in read-write mode without emptying it. However, if the new contents are shorter than the old contents, you won't remove the trailing data.

Stick with the second version. It's more readable and it works as expected.